# Polchinski Weyl Anomaly from perturbing the flat background. Eq (3.4.22)

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, path-integral, quantum-anomalies

In deriving the Weyl anomaly for the bosonic string using a perturbation around  a flat background, Polchinksi uses Eq. (3.4.22), i.e.
$$
\ln \frac{ Z[\delta+h] }{Z[\delta]} \approx\, \frac{1}{8\pi^2}\int d^2 z \int d^2 z'\, h_{\bar{z}\bar{z}}(z,\bar{z}) h_{\bar{z}\bar{z}}(z',\bar{z}') \left\langle T_{zz}(z)  T_{zz}(z') \right \rangle_\delta. \tag{3.4.22}
$$
I realise it is better to ask one question per post, but I have two questions about this equation so I hope I will be allowed a minor transgression of the generally preffered rules.

1. Isn't he missing a factor $Z[\delta]^{-1}$ on the RHS?
2. Isn't there another contribution quadratic in $h_{\bar{z}\bar{z}}$?

---

Let me explain in more detail.

Question 1: This equation follows from second order perturbation theory of the functional
$$
Z[\delta+h] = \int [dX\, db\, dc\,] e^{-S[X,b,c,\delta+h]}
$$
where $S$ is the total action (matter + ghosts). Expanding around the flat metric
$$
S[X,b,c,\delta+h] =\, S[X,b,c,\delta] + h \frac{\delta S[X,b,c,g]}{\delta g}\Bigg|_{g=\delta} +  o(h^2)
$$
Using $\delta S /\delta g = (\sqrt{g}/4\pi) T$ we introduce the energy momentum tensor and get
$$
Z[\delta+h] =\,  \int [dX\, db\, dc\,] \exp-\left(  S[X,b,c,\delta] +  \frac{h}{4\pi} T +  o(h^2)\right) \label{eq:c3hhwpor}
$$
From this we have
\begin{align*}
\ln \frac{ Z[\delta+h] }{Z[\delta]} =&\, \ln \frac{  \int [dX\, db\, dc\,] e^{-\left(  S[X,b,c,\delta] +  \frac{h}{4\pi} T +  o(h^2)\right)}}{ Z[\delta]}\nonumber\\
= &\, \ln \frac{  \int [dX\, db\, dc\,] e^{-S[X,b,c,\delta] } \big[1-(1/2) (hT/4\pi)^2+ \cdots \big]} {Z[\delta]}\nonumber\\
\sim &\, \ln \left[ 1- \frac{1}{2 (4\pi)^2 Z[\delta] } \int [dX\, db\, dc\,] e^{-S[X,b,c,\delta] } h^2 T^2  \right] \nonumber\\
= &\,  \frac{1}{2 (4\pi)^2Z[\delta]} \int [dX\, db\, dc\,] e^{-S[X,b,c,\delta] } h^2 T^2  = \frac{1}{2 (4\pi)^2 Z[\delta]}\left\langle h^2 T^2 \right \rangle_\delta 
\end{align*}
Here $\langle \; \rangle_\delta$ means that the expectation value is taken with a Euclidean metric, $g=\delta$. In the second line, we have only written down explicitly the contribution quadratic in $h$; all the other contributions are in the dots. In the third line we have ignored all these other contributions as they play no role in Polchinski's argument. (We have ignored all indices, but if you put them back in and are careful about all factor you do get exactly (3.4.22), except for the $Z[\delta]^{-1}$.)

This brings me to my first question: isn't Polchinski missing a factor $Z[\delta]^{-1}$ on the RHS?

Moreover, if you work out the $\left\langle h^2 T^2 \right \rangle_\delta $ contribution you get a $\left\langle c/2\right\rangle$ contribution and 
$\left\langle c/2 \right\rangle =  (c/2) Z[\delta]$, so that $Z[\delta]$ cancels the one in the denominator.

Question 2:
In the expansion of the action around the flat metric, we have only considered the term linear in $h$, which is of the form $h \delta S /\delta g \sim h T$. We have then expanded the exponential and used its second order contribution to end up with something of the form $\int hh \langle TT\rangle$.  But what about the second order term in $h$ in the expansion of the action, $(1/2) h^2 \delta^2 S/\delta g^2 |_{g=\delta}$.

Does the first order expansion of $\exp[-(1/2) h^2 \delta^2 S/\delta g^2 |_{g=\delta}]$ not contribute as well to the second order expansion in $h$?

Comment: I think that $Z^{-1}$ included in defenition of $\langle TT\rangle$.

Comment: Not according to his definition (3.4.2). But you are right that had he defined it in this way, this factor would not have appeared. In any case, both ways lead to the same final answer, so question 1 is the simple one. I am just wondering more about question 2.

Comment: regarding your Q2: the term you're referring to gives rise to a contact term, and as Polchinski already stated above (3.4.21) he's ignoring contact terms. So presumably you can remove it by renormalising the worldsheet cosmological constant (and perhaps dilaton). This https://www.emis.de//journals/SIGMA/2015/047/ is also useful.

Comment: @ Wakabaloola Thanks. I'll have a look at the paper you mention.